# How to use another method's variable in a vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I have two methods in a vue component.

First makes the user choose from a v-select, either itemone or itemtwo. Then, to retreive the value for later i call @change to assign the variable to a method declared later - `getItemValue`.

Second is a submit button, when clicked, we go to `handleSubmit`.

After `handleSubmit` is called, I want to use the value I got from `getItemValue` (in variable `theItem`), but how can I call another method if it's out of my scope?

**Mycomponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
    lazy-validation
  >
    <v-select
      v-model="select"
      :items="items"
      @change="getItemValue"
    ></v-select>

    <v-btn
      @click="handleSubmit"
    >
      Submit
    </v-btn>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({    
      items: [
        'itemone',
        'itemtwo'
      ],
    }),
    methods: {
        getItemValue(theItem) {

        },
        handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            // i need "theItem" here!
        }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` already writes to your local variable, so there is absolutely no need to setup a `get` method to write the select value to a variable.

[Actually, v-model is a bit more complicated than just 'write' to a variable](https://alligator.io/vuejs/add-v-model-support/), but the important bit is that in your template you are setting up `v-model="select"`, which basically means that whenever the user uses the select to pick a value, your local `select` variable will be updated with the selected value.

Now, there is no `select` in your example component `data`, I don't know why. But if you had it, you could just sent that variable in your `handleSubmit`:

```
<template>
  <v-form
    ref="form"
    v-model="valid"
    lazy-validation
  >
    <v-select
      v-model="select"
      :items="items"
    ></v-select>

    <v-btn
      @click="handleSubmit"
    >
      Submit
    </v-btn>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      select: '',
      items: [
        'itemone',
        'itemtwo'
      ],
    }),
    methods: {
        handleSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            doSomethingWith(this.select); // this will be updated at this point
            // with the option the user selected
        }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Now, however, be aware that **if the `select` variable is a component prop**, then you should not do this right away, since props are not intended to be modified directly by child components. If that would be the case, please update your question with more info.

Comment: Wow amazing, thank you. Just for curiosity, what happends if the select variable is a prop?

Comment: Check this article about mutating props: https://michaelnthiessen.com/avoid-mutating-prop-directly

Answer (score 0):

You would simple set the variable (`theItem`) value to the data

```
getItemValue(theItem) {
  this.theItem;
},
```

and then retrieve it later

```
handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault()
  // i need "theItem" here!
  // simple access theItem
  console.log('theItem', this.theItem);
}
```